# Python Indexing Tuples

Tags: python

I am creating a function, this function when applied to a tuple it should return the even indexed element in the tuple. How comes it's not returning the fourth indexed element?

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    '''
    aTup: a tuple

    returns: tuple, every other element of aTup. 
    '''
    evenIndex = ()
    evenTuple = ()
    for i in aTup:
        if aTup.index(i)%2 == 0:
            evenIndex = evenIndex +  (aTup.index(i),)
            evenTuple += (aTup[aTup.index(i)],)
    return evenTuple
```

Comment: Why not use slicing? `t = (0,1,2,3,4,5,); odds = t[1::2]; evens = t[::2]`

Comment: Thank you all, I guess slicing will work for me

Answer (score 4):

Using `a.index` will return the index of the first occurrence of the item. You can't really count on that when the items in your tuple are not unique.

You should consider using `enumerate` instead:

```
for i, v in enumerate(aTup):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        ...
```

You can better still use *slicing* and be less verbose:

```
aTup[::2] # starts at zero, stops at the length of the tuple, steps in 2s
```

---

Also, keep in mind that *indexing* starts from `0` by default. But with `enumerate` you can make it start from a selected number:

```
for i, v in enumerate(aTup, 1) # starts counting from 1
```

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me. Tuples start indexes at 0. So if you have tuple:

> (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

it returns

> (0, 2, 4, 6)

If you want 4th, youll need to change

```
if i % 2 == 0:
```

into

```
if i % 2 == 1:
```